# MapKit Search API like in Apple Maps App

Tags: objective-c, swift, mapkit

How can I implement the same search that the Apple Maps app has? Is this a MKLocal search function? How can it be local if it searches the world?

Answer (score 2):

The class is indeed named `MKLocalSearch`, but it is recommended (not *required*) to specify a region where to search for the entered query. See the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/EnablingSearch/EnablingSearch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH10-SW1).